# nginx more than one ssl configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, user-agent

I config  the ssl in nginx.conf as following, and it works fine:

```
    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/security/test.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/security/test.key;
        location / {
        }
    }
```

But the above configured ssl certificates do not support ie6, so i apply another group certificates, but it will be a gray lock ,not a green one.
So i only want to use the new group certificates for ie6, for other browsers, i still want to use the old ones.
I think if there are some code as bellow could solve my problem:

```
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 6.0" ) {
       ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/security/test_ie6.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/security/test_ie6.key;
    }else{
       ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/security/test.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/security/test.key;
    }
    location / {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have different certificates for a different browser in a way you envision.
Your attempt is to detect the browser version based on the user agent, but this information is only available after the successful TLS handshake, i.e after the certificate was already sent.

But, modern browsers you the [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to indicate which server they want to connect to in case multiple servers are behind the same IP address. Older browsers like IE 8.0 on XP and also IE 6.0 don't support this extension. Thus you could configure a certificate for a specific hostname (SNI) inside a section with the specific server_name (`server_name example.com`) and then configure a default certificate for the site in the default section (`server_name _`). SNI capable browsers will use the name specific certificate while all the others will fall back to the default certificate.